# upload contact on server in phonegap

Tags: cordova, file-upload, cordova-plugins, contacts

I have installed plugin `cordova-plugin-contacts` to fetch a single contact.

Here is the code snippet

```
$('body').on("click", "#btnAttachment", function () {


     navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){

         alert(JSON.stringify(contact));

     },function(err){
         console.log('Error: ' + err);
     });

});
```

I am getting all things in `contact` object.

Now I want to upload a contact on server as a vcf file or by any other suitable method.
I have the url provided just want to make a post call.
Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ajax to upload contact to server.

```
$.ajax({
    url: API_URL + 'url-to-server',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        contact_name: "value-for-parameter-contact_name",
        contact_number: "0123456789",
        contact_email: "aa@xyz.com",
        contact_other_detais: ""
    }, error: function(){
      
          },
    success: function(data) {
        //this function will call on success.
    },

});
```

you can find more help about ajax here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

> Edited:**Using file**

If you really want to do that you can done by following way:

You need to install **cordova-plugin-file-transfer** https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer
This can be used for create vCard and upload to server.

**if you want Device automatically handle vCard file, You need to follow RFC 6350 vCard instruction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard or https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350**

```
//p is your person object(have all contact details).
function writeFile(p) {
   var type = window.TEMPORARY;
   var size = 1*1024*1024; // file size

   window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

   function successCallback(fs) {
       
       // The path for contact.vcf file is:\data\data\'your-package-name-goes-here'\cache
      fs.root.getFile('contact.vcf', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

         fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
               alert('Write completed.');
               // Now you can upload this file to server
               
               upload(fileEntry);
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
               alert('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
            };

            
            var vCardFile ="BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\nN:" + p.getSurname() + ";" + p.getFirstName() + "\r\nFN:" + p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getSurname() + "\r\nORG:" + p.getCompanyName() + "\r\nTITLE:" + p.getTitle() + "\r\nTEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" + p.getWorkPhone() + "\r\nTEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" + p.getHomePhone() + "\r\nADR;TYPE=WORK:;;" + p.getStreet() + ";" + p.getCity() + ";" + p.getState() + ";" + p.getPostcode() + ";" + p.getCountry() + "\r\nEMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:" + p.getEmailAddress() + "\r\nEND:VCARD\r\n";
            
            
            fileWriter.write(vCardFile); //vCardFile is your Formatted string VCF format.
         }, errorCallback);

      }, errorCallback);

   }

   function errorCallback(error) {
      alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
   }
}







function upload(fileEntry) {
   
    var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();

    var success = function (r) {
        console.log("Successful upload...");
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        // displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + " (content uploaded to server)");
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";

    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    // SERVER must be a URL that can handle the request, like
    // http://some.server.com/upload.php
    ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI(SERVER), success, fail, options);
};
```

After uploading, you can delete temporary vCard file using:

```
fileEntry.remove(function() {
            alert('File removed.');
         }, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Can it done by uploading a vcf file..? i.e by putting contact into vcf file and then process to upload ?
solution which you have given is also right I tried the same but can it be done by uploading vcf file ?

Comment: its like a chat app...I can write text as well as upload contact...so when uploaded a contact...i also have to differentiate between contact and text...that is the reason why i need help related to vcf file.

Comment: you can also done it by creating vcf file, then upload to server.

Comment: But it is not good solution, for vcf file, 
first you need to create file using file writer (file writer is not directly available in cordova, you need plugin to do that) then you need to upload that file.
And on other side when you want to read that vcf file, again you need plugin to read from file. So it is very typical.
i am suggesting you that, only send required details to server and get back from server.

Comment: Can you post an answer for the same if possible.?...i.e putting contact in vcf file and then upload ?

Comment: will try the same and let you know...thanks for editing.

Comment: can you help me out in reading same vcf file from server and extracting contact details from it ?
also posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261828/read-uploaded-vcf-file-from-server