# read uploaded vcf file from server

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have uploaded vcf file successfully on server on getting help from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115491/upload-contact-on-server-in-phonegap/41115734#41115734) (the one which is edited)

Now I need a help in how to read that vcf file or vcard from server and display as a contact number and contact name in my phonegap app.

plugin used `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plugin cordova-plugin-file-transfer https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer you can download file from server.

For Read vcf file, you need https://github.com/nilclass/vcardjs JavaScript based library. you can directly use .js files.

You can follow below example.

```
 window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {

        console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
        var fileName = "temp.vcf";
        var dirEntry = fs.root;
        dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

           download(fileEntry,"server-path-to-file.vcf");

        }, onErrorCreateFile);

    }, onErrorLoadFs);




function download(fileEntry, uri) {

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        fileURL,
        function (entry) {
            console.log("Successful download...");
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            readFile(entry);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        null, // or, pass false
        {
            //headers: {
            //    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            //}
        }
    );
}


function readFile(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {

            console.log("Successful file read: " + reader.result);
            reader.parseVCard(reader.result);

        };

        reader.readAsText(file);

    }, onErrorReadFile);
}

function parseVCard(vCarddata){
VCF.parse(vCarddata, function(vcard) {
  // this function is called with a VCard instance.
  // If the input contains more than one vCard, it is called multiple times.
  console.log("Formatted name", vcard.fn);
  console.log("Names", JSON.stringify(vcard.n));
});
//Fore more help:https://github.com/nilclass/vcardjs
}
```

Comment: hope you remember this thread.
I am using this dynamically...Do I need to change my file name every time I download .vcf file ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create file name dynamically.(var fileName = "temp.vcf";).
you can use unique id as file name.